# Android garbage collection doesn't collect, causing visual glitches

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-management, garbage-collection

I'm creating a android application with a navigation drawer and fragements. but when I load a view with a lot of resources, or with a lot of canvas drawing (in this case graphs, [For the Graphs I'm using this lib](https://bitbucket.org/danielnadeau/holographlibrary/wiki/Home))  the naviagation drawer gets stuck for e couple milliseconds so I did some research and I found out that I should free all my views I use in my fragment when I close the fragment. So here is the example that I do for all my fragments
**GRAPHFRAGMENT**

```
public class GraphFragment() extends Fragment{
        private MainActivity parrentActivity;
        private View view;
        private Callback callback;
        private SystemInfoTask systemInfoTask;
        private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
        private LineGraph ramGraph;
        private Button ramBtn;
        private LineGraph cpuGraph;
        private Button cpuBtn;
        private LineGraph lan1Graph;
        private Button lan1Btn;
        private LineGraph lan2Graph;
        private Button lan2Btn;

    private void defineViews() {
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh_layout);
        ramGraph = (LineGraph) view.findViewById(R.id.ram_graph);
        cpuGraph = (LineGraph) view.findViewById(R.id.cpu_graph);
        lan1Graph = (LineGraph) view.findViewById(R.id.lan1_graph);
        lan2Graph = (LineGraph) view.findViewById(R.id.lan2_graph);
        ramBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.ram_btn);
        cpuBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.cpu_btn);
        lan1Btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.lan1_btn);
        lan2Btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.lan2_btn);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        swipeRefreshLayout = null;
        ramGraph = null;
        cpuGraph = null;
        lan1Graph = null;
        lan2Graph = null;
        ramBtn = null;
        cpuBtn = null;
        lan1Btn = null;
        lan2Btn = null;
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        if (neworktask!= null) {
            neworktask.cancel();
            neworktask= null;
        }
    }
}
```

So after that I thought that the glitches should be gone because the garbadge collector can collect my whole fragment because alle references are gone. So when I Run my application and create this example

DEFAULT OPENING FRAGMENT
 - Now I open the navigation drawer  **pic 1**
 - Now I open my fragment with the graphs  **pic 2**
 - And then I open the navigation drawer again to open the first fragment again. **pic 3**
 - This is what I did a couple of times and the checked my memory
   analyser in android studio**pic 4**

the last picture is my memory analyser **pic 5**

black arrow is opening the graph fragment
yellow errow is  initiate garbage collection

Please help me what am I doing wrong?

PIC 1 -> [image: pic 1]

[image: pic 2]

[image: pic 3]

[image: pic 4]

[image: pic 5]

Comment: I hate to tell you this, but nulling out those variables does absolutely nothing.  Whatever source you read it from doesn't know what they're talking about.

Comment: how? serious? what else do I need to do?